# Есть ли способ скидывать звонок от знакомых и незнакомых контактов через свой апп?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

Доброго времени суток! Не нашёл решения, при котором на iOS можно реджектить входящие звонки. Возможно у вас есть решение или вы сталкивались с этим?
Прошу прощения за неоднозначный вопрос.
Благодарю.

Comment: Как вы принимаете звонки? Добавте в вопрос релевантный код.

Comment: @0xdb дело в том, что я не разрабатываю на iOS. Меня интересует возможно ли на данной оси такое решение. Т.к. специалисты не дают однозначного ответа. Т.е. звонки должны скидываться как при включенном режиме "Не беспокоить"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это невозможно, вы можете блокировать звонки которые приходят именно в свое приложение, а обычные звонки нельзя никак отменить.

Answer (score 2):

Нет, на iOS невозможно такое без jailbreak.

При наличии jailbreak можете найти решение, но будет ли оно нужным.